How to estimate the latency of communication?
I am running an application that involves many rounds of communication. For example, there are 30 rounds, and each round transmits approximately 0.1 MB of data. I have set the bandwidth to around 50 MB/s and the ping latency to 10 ms. I am wondering if, given the small amount of data, each communication will fully utilize the bandwidth, allowing me to estimate the time as 0.1 MB / 50 MB/s = 0.002 s?

Where are the two endpoints of your roads of communication? Same server? Different servers on the same network in the same location? Servers in remote locations? What does ping tell you? What protocol is used for the communication? If it uses connections, is the same connection re-used or is a new connection set up for each round? What do you mean by "I have set the bandwidth ... and the ping latency"? Is this a network conditioner setting, or a simulation, or...?

Also, who sends what, and does any side need to wait for anything from the other side, even if it's just confirmation that the data has already been received?

Another thing... What is it you actually want to measure? The latency, or the achievable throughput?

The two endpoints are actually two Docker containers running on a single machine. The bandwidth and ping latency are controlled using the tc tool in Linux. I believe the connection is already established, and all communication can utilize it.
I am asking this question because I am not sure whether the bandwidth can be fully utilized. I wonder about this because I know that computational hardware resources are often difficult to fully utilize, and I am curious whether a similar situation occurs with bandwidth resources.

See the issues with the lack of sliding windows in protocols such as XMODEM, or too small window sizes in TCP for reasons why the full bandwidth could not necessarily be all used. We lack details on the protocol and what is going over it to tell you whether you will be able to use everything or not.


I am wondering if, given the small amount of data, each communication will fully utilize the bandwidth, allowing me to estimate the time as 0.1 MB / 50 MB/s = 0.002 s?

The amount of data matters primarily for congestion control algorithms. If you are sending your data over TCP, for example, then the TCP connection will deliberately pace the transmission at first ('slow start') until it "ramps up" to what it considers the maximum acceptable speed. So if you re-use the same TCP connection, then the 1st "0.1 MB" round may take a bit longer, but subsequent rounds should eventually reach the calculated 0.002 seconds/round.
On the other hand, if you make a new TCP connection for each round, then all of them will go through the 'slow start' phase (plus of course the TCP handshake itself). This is one of the reasons web browsers re-use TCP connections for multiple HTTP requests.
If you are using a different transport protocol the results can differ. (Removing the congestion control wouldn't make it a guaranteed 0.002s, however – it could also become 'infinity' in case there is actual congestion and some of your packets are dropped midway.)

This answer kinda dances around the core issue, that the speed of a single link is the maximum amount that can be received before packets start getting dropped, higher level protocols like TCP are just trying to detect/optimize for that in the face of congestion.

There may be multiple levels of handshaking, not only TCP, but e.g. TLS, HTTP, authentication, Websockets, etc.

This will vary greatly depending on your setup.
If you have:

a single, already established, stream (e.g. a raw TCP connection, or even a TLS connection), with appropriate window sizes
and you can send your data without having to wait for anything (including confirmation of previous data having been received) from the other side
and the link is actually capable of transmitting 50 MB/s,

then nothing prevents you from sending 0.1 MB every 2 ms (of course you need both endpoints to actually be capable of sending and receiving/processing that much data at that rate). But then latency is quite meaningless, though of course there will be "physical" latency for the data to get from the source to the destination (5 or 10 ms in your setup, depending on whether the 10 ms are one-way or round-trip).
At the other end of the spectrum, if each round involves a new HTTPS connection, and you need that request to be finished before you can go on, then it will take several round-trips (so multiples of your "ping latency") to establish the connection (TCP handshake, TLS handshake, possibly HTTP request/response depending on who sends the data...), then you send the data, then you wait for the response/acknowledgement (yet another roundtrip). It could easily take over 100 ms for one single exchange.
And there are lots of intermediate possibilities in between, where the latency for each round could range from 10 ms (your "ping latency") to large multiples of that. Even just having the wait for a confirmation, or one side having to wait for all data before it can start sending a response, will add latency and kill throughput.
There's also the risk that you may have more or less overhead. Sending a 0.1 MB stream over TCP is one thing. Sending 5000 20-byte packets (that's 0.1 MB as well) will involve a lot more overhead (it could easily double the required bandwidth in some cases).
Without a much more detailed description of your setup, it's completely impossible to stay where you will stand.
